# sum of grouped rows of two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm somehow stuck on a very simple task..

I have two tables:

```
TABLE A:
name  time
name1 100
name2  50
name1 200
name3 100
name2  50

TABLE B:
name time
name3 100
name1  50
name3 200
name2 100
name1  50
```

All I want to have is a list of the first 2 names with highest time in total!

Something like this (but this dowsn't work ofc)

```
SELECT  a.name 
        , SUM(a.time) as time1
        , (SELECT SUM(time) FROM table2 b WHERE b.name = a.name GROUP BY a.name) as time2
        , time1 + time2 as total
FROM table1 a
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would the desired result set look like? And why do you have two tables?

Comment: are the two tables related at all so that you could `JOIN` them? if not, then you'll need a `union` query to select from both, then a container query to do your `top 2` names.

Comment: @Strawberry: the desired result should look like this: 1. name3 600 2. name1 400

Comment: amend your question accordingly

Comment: @MarcB: well, they are not directly related. just the names are the same

Comment: then a `select ... (select * from a union all select * from b)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with something like:

```
SELECT
  name,
  SUM(time) AS total_time
  FROM (
    SELECT name, time FROM table_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, time FROM table_b
  ) AS u
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY total_time DESC
  LIMIT 2
;
```

Here's a [working sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35e29/31/0) with your data.

Comment: thanks, but this is not workin coirrectly. the sums are incorrect. name 1 should have 400, not 800 for example

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? I corrected my answer, `UNION ALL` is the way to go. The approach is similar to @Rob's, even though I think mine is a bit cleaner ;-)

Comment: yea, thanks. that's a bit cleaner, you are right. anyway thanks to Rob, too

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
SELECT name, SUM( timeA + timeB ) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT name, time as timeA, 0 as timeB
    FROM a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, 0 as timeA, time as timeB
    FROM b
) AS times
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total DESC
```